# How to get data from recycler view onclick android studio firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

How can I get email when clicking my recycler view based on the position? After clicking recycler view I want the email of the particular position to be retrieved for editing purposes. Now I am only able to get the Id of documents when clicked and I have tried getting the email from the UserInfo but it won't work. Please help.

## UserInfo

```
public class UserInfo {
    private String item_id;
    private String Email;
    private String FName;


private UserInfo(){}

private UserInfo(String Email, String FName, String item_id){
    this.Email = Email;
    this.FName = FName;
    this.item_id = item_id;
}

public String getEmail(){
    return Email;
}
public void setEmail(String Email){
    this.Email = Email;
}
public String getFName(){
    return FName;
}
public void setFName(String FName){
    this.FName = FName;
}


public String getItem_id() {
    return item_id;
}

public void setItem_id(String item_id) {
    this.item_id = item_id;
}
}
```

## Admin Fragment

```
public class AdminFragment extends Fragment implements FirestoreAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    RecyclerView myRecycleView;
    private FirestoreAdapter adapter;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    Button Btn;

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_admin, container, false);
    myRecycleView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    Btn = v.findViewById(R.id.editBtn);

    fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    Query query = fStore.collection("users");
    PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder().setInitialLoadSizeHint(10).setPageSize(3).build();
    FirestorePagingOptions<UserInfo> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<UserInfo>().setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .setQuery(query, config, new SnapshotParser<UserInfo>() {
                @NonNull
                @Override
                public UserInfo parseSnapshot(@NonNull DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
                    UserInfo userInfo = snapshot.toObject(UserInfo.class);
                    String itemId = snapshot.getId();
                    userInfo.setItem_id(itemId);
                    return userInfo;
                }
            }).build();

    adapter = new FirestoreAdapter(options, this);

    myRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    myRecycleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
    myRecycleView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = UserInfo.getEmail();
            fAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Password Reset link sent to your registered E-Mail!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to send reset email!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });

        }
    });
    return v;
}


@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot snapshot, int position) {
    Log.d("Item_CLICK", "Clicked the item : " + position + "and the ID:" + snapshot.getId());
}

}
```

## Firestore Adapter

```
public class FirestoreAdapter extends FirestorePagingAdapter<UserInfo, FirestoreAdapter.UserViewHolder> {
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

public FirestoreAdapter(@NonNull FirestorePagingOptions<UserInfo> options, OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    super(options);
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull UserInfo model) {
    holder.list_email.setText(model.getEmail());
    holder.list_fname.setText(model.getFName());
}

@NonNull
@Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);

    return new UserViewHolder(view);
}

public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    private TextView list_email;
    private TextView list_fname;
    public UserViewHolder(@NonNull View itemview) {
        super(itemview);

        list_email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        list_fname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        itemview.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onItemClickListener.onItemClick(getItem(getAdapterPosition()), getAdapterPosition());

    }
}
public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot snapshot, int position);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot snapshot, int position) {
    UserInfo userInfo = snapshot.toObject(UserInfo.class);
    Log.d("Item_CLICK", "Clicked the item : " + position + "and the ID:" + userInfo.getEmail()+" and the fname"+userInfo.getFName());
}
```

Comment: then if I want to put that value into string email in Admin Fragment, how am I suppose to get that value into my string email?

Comment: this above mentioned method will be in admin fragment. you can create a email variable in admin fragment. and assign the email value to that local variable.